# ReSharper find code issues not show all result

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I can view only part of the results (681).

How can I view all results (1694)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the funnel icon with the purple exclamation mark next to `Group by` text on the icon bar to open `Filter Issues` window and select `Check All` button there.